# You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, stream, observable, angular13

[image][image]Using the command "npm i rxjs@6.4.0" to change the rxjs from 7.4.0 to 6.4.0 does not the solve the problem

This is the ts file

```
  get errorMessageForPassword(): string {
    const form: FormControl = (this.thirdFormGroup.get('passWord') as FormControl);
    return form.hasError('required') ?
      'Password is required' :
      form.hasError('minlength') ?
        'Password must be at least 6 characters' : '';
  }
```

This the html file

```
         <div class="col-md form-group">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                            <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" placeholder="**"
                                formControlName="passWord"  [(ngModel)]="testUser.passWord" id="passWord"
                                name="passWord" >
                            <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">
                                <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            <mat-error>{{ errorMessageForPassword }}</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I fixed the issue. The problem was how I handled the property declaration of password in the formGroup validator function.
The first  code snippet is how I handled the validators which was in the **wrong** format when using **formbuilder**.

```
  passWord: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)],
```

The second code snippet is the **correct** format when using formbuilder

```
 passWord: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
```

Screenshot of code snippet https://prnt.sc/imbgwE7AlRTr

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that you forgot to add parantheses to

`{{errorMessageForPassword()}}`

(I checked the example here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples#form-field-error)

Comment: no because, I have used a function similar to that just with different name and it worked fine within the same html file

Comment: Ok. As the error message does not seem to be your problem, can you show where you use Observables?

Comment: see updated post on observables are handled. Please note that this file is not user defined.